# Auto Generate text field (in InfoPath 2010) from a SharePoint 2010 list

Tags: infopath

I am currently working on a project that requires me to have a drop down list (that has a data connection to a SharePoint 2010 list) and a text box field within a repeating table.  My issue that I am having is that when I go to run the form, the text box field (Course-Number) is getting populated from the drop-down list (Course) however, when I go to add a new item to the table the Course-Number field is populating the same data from the first item of the list.

I have created a rule on the Course field to generate the Course Number in the Course-Number field when the Course is selected from the drop down box.

```
The rule is as follows:
Condition: Course is not blank
Rule type: Action
Run these actions:
   Set a field's value
     Field: Course-Number
     Value: Class-Number[Title = Course]  ---Class-Number and Title being from the data connection and Course being the drop down box field.
```

Can anyone help me to figure out how to make this work properly?

Like I mentioned above, I need to be able to add multiple items to the repeating table (where the drop down box and text box live) and have the text box generate the data from the "current" drop down box.